# Can you use an iPhone 5 to call if you have internet service, but no cell service?

Tags: wifi, iphone

I have an iPhone 5.  The place I'm moving to has a wi-fi network in place, but there's no cell service (it's in the mountains).

Is there any way to use my iPhone to make/receive calls over the wi-fi network?  I'd like it very much if people can still call me while I'm at home.

Comment: Skype or FaceTime (audio) unless you get a mobile cell spot from a provider that you can put into the WiFi network and then get the cellular network at home.

Comment: seems to be a new feature in iOS 9 that will work with iPhone 5c and later https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203032

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the WiFi connection has enough bandwidth for audio, you could install [Skype](http://www.skype.com/) and use [SkypeIn](http://www.skype.com/en/features/online-number/)/[SkypeOut](http://www.skype.com/en/features/call-phones-and-mobiles/) to be reachable via a phone number.

Comment: And as an addtion: It is possible to create a phone number in skype (https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA331/what-is-a-skype-number).
So you could just redirect your calls from your cell phone to your skype number if your cell phone has no service.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, it won't work (directly) and not like you would like it.

If you want to call someone over wifi you need to use a VoIP service/use the SIP protocol.

The only possibility if you want someone to call you on your actual mobile number you need to get a [femtocell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Femtocell) to extend (very) localy the cellular network.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?  It sounds like you're saying there is a way, but that you have to do...something different.

Comment: TLDR : You won't be able to do what you want without a Femtocell.

Answer (score 1):

Another one to have a look is WhatsApp or Viber. Both these apps allow you to make calls to other uses who have them installed. These use Data rather than a cellular network. the only problem is the person you are calling will need to have these installed.

Just another option for you rather than having to setup skype account.

Comment: Can you confirm that these work when there is no cell service and the app isn't running to alert that an incoming call is in progress?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook messenger for calls. Theres a icon of a phone beside the name of the contact when u open message window. Its crystal clear sound. Just turn on mic in settings.

Answer (score 0):

Notwithstanding the previous answers, someone has already mentioned a VoIP service.  To add more details, you can register with a VoIP hosting company, who will provide you with a login to their service.

With software like Zopier[1] you can make outbound calls from your phone.  You won't be able to receive inbound calls unless you actually register a number (which will cost for 'line rental') with a VoIP service, and set up call forwarding when you do have cellular signal from your mobile number to that VoIP number.

Regrettably, without a Femtocell there's no alternative to this for text messaging except for iMessage, so unless all of your contacts are on iOS you don't have a choice here.

[1] there are others - some more here: http://appadvice.com/appguides/show/voip-apps-for-ios